# Why does transfering files from one USB device to another on the same PC goes slower than normal?

Tags: usb

I have a brand new ACER laptop with USB A and C ports, and the controller is USB 3.2 Gen 2 (10 Gbit) on all ports.

When I transfer files from a USB stick (that also supports USB 10 Gbit) to the computer (or vice versa), the transfer speed is ~600 MB/s. When I transfer files from that USB stick to an external SSD which also supports USB 10 Gbit, the transfer speed is only 150 MB/s.

Why is that?

When I run a synthetic disk-benchmark, both USB devices reach 1000 MB read speed, and 900 MB write speed, so the laptop and the 2 storage devices are definitely USB 10 Gbit. When I connect one of the devices to the laptop and transfer files to or from it, it reaches write speeds of around 600 MB/s, so that is the 'real world' speed. BUT, when I attach both devices to the laptop, and transfer files from one to the other, the transfer speed drops to 150 MB/s. The external SSD is a Samsung T7 1 TB with a 6 inch long USB cable, and the USB stick is a Kingston Datatraveler Max 512 GB.

---

P.S. The storage device in the laptop is an NVMe SSD with a transferspeed of more than 1500 MB/s, so that also isn't the bottleneck. I have a suspicion that 600 MB/s is the maximum speed the USB-controller can handle, and when you use more than one USB-device at a time, that speed is divided between the connected devices. Can anybody confirm this?

---

I used the program USBtreeview, and found out that the USB-connectors on the left of the laptop are on the USB 10 Gbit controller, and the USB-connector on the right is on the USB 5 Gbit controller. When I connect 2 devices to the left side of the laptop, I get a transferspeed of only 150 MB/s. When I connect one of the devices to the USB connector on the left, and the other on the right, the transferspeed is suddenly 300-350 MB/s. It is still not 600 MB/s what I get when I transfer data to or from one USB-device, but it is of course better than 150 MB/s. It looks like the USB-controllers in the laptop can only handle so much data at a time.

Comment: Just to make sure, do you also get 600 MB/s from the computer when writing to the external SSD? Depending on the SSD, Read speeds can be significantly faster than Write. How big is the file? Windows will use disk write caching to speed up writing files to internal drives, but I think it's off for USB/external drives by default. A big enough file will start fast, but eventually slow down once the cache is full

Comment: Sounds like the cable is the limiting factor or the port isn’t actually USB 3.2 Gen 2. The USB naming convention on the versions suck, confuse even the most educated engineers, which leave everyone else mistaking a USB 3.2 Gen 1 port for a 3.2 Gen 2 port. 600 MB/sec transfer suggests its connection is at USB 3.2 Gen 1 speeds

Comment: That can be the case. Computers will often have multiple USB controllers. Finding which ports are connected to which and then testing from a port connected to one controller to a port connected to a different controller can give you better transfer rates.

Comment: Please transfer the replies to the text of your original question